# PdfPages has no effect on my document size

Tags: pdfpages

I am writing an abstract for a conference and they gave a TeX template. It is very important that the created pdf file has the size 180mm x 237mm. Last year I used the same template for my abstract and the size of my pdf document was fine. The template did not change, but this year the size of the paper is A4 although it was set with `pdfpagewidth` and `pdfpageheight` to be smaller.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}



 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Set dimensions of columns, gap between columns, and paragraph indent
%Please do not change/delete any of the settings in the following section as they
%guarantee the correct formatting of your paper.
\setlength{\textheight}{217mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{160mm}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{180mm}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{237mm}

\setlength{\columnsep}{8mm}

\setlength{\topmargin}{0mm}

\setlength{\footskip}{0mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{0mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0mm}
\setlength{\topskip}{0mm}

\setlength{\voffset}{-15mm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-15mm}

\newcommand{\Section}[1]{\vspace{-8pt}\section{\hskip -1em.~~#1}\vspace{-3pt}}
\newcommand{\SubSection}[1]{\vspace{-3pt}\subsection{\hskip -1em.~~#1}
  \vspace{-3pt}}

\pagestyle{empty}

%end of dimension settings
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}


\twocolumn[
\centering{\LARGE \bf Replace this sentence with the title of your abstract} %% Please include your paper title here!

 \vskip10mm

 \begin{flushleft}
 {\small Firstname1 Lastname1 (1,2), Firstname2 Lastname2 (2) and           Firstname3 Lastname3 (1) OR Firstname1 Lastname1 (1) and/for the
 Team-Name\\%% Please include author name(s) in this/these line(s) and      make sure to use full first and last names!
presenting author (if already known) shall be in bold (e.g. {\bf B. Bman});
if there is only one affiliation, do not use any numbering (e.g. A. Aman, B. Bman and C. Cman)\\
(1) Institute of Physics, Alaska, USA, (2) University of Katlenburg-Lindau, Germany (your@address.com)} %Please include affiliations here!
\end{flushleft}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Please do not change/delete the following vskip command as it
%guarantees the correct distance between abstract information and abstract text.
\vskip10mm %
 ]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\thispagestyle{empty}

\section*{Abstract} % Abstract section

This is the abstract section of your paper. Please replace these     instructions
 with the text of your abstract. The text will appear in two columns. In the
final abstract file (after uploading into Copernicus Office)
each of those two columns are 75 mm wide. If you are including figures,     tables and equations,
they MUST be imported into this file. The text will automatically wrap to     a second page if necessary.

\Section{Introduction} % Introduction

This is the introduction section of your paper. All section headings are     in a large
bold font. All sections and subsections are numbered, respectively.      Please
use the Latex command ``$\backslash$Section'' for a numbered section,
``$\backslash$section*'' (with an asterisk) for an unnumbered section and
``$\backslash$SubSection'' for a sub-section. The sections and      sub-sections are consecutively numbered.

\SubSection{Sub-Section} % Sub-section

This is the example of a sub-section. As mentioned above, please use the
command ``$\backslash$SubSection\{Your sub-section title\}'' in order to      include
your sub-section title in the correct formatting. The sub-sections are also
 consecutively numbered.

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: So, sorry, the question is, what is wrong? How can I get the right format?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please add a  **full** minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Does it work with .tex file from last year? If yes you could use it ....

Comment: What does `pdfpages` have to do with this?

Comment: The template uses pdfpages and the size of the page is set with: \setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{180mm}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{237mm}

Comment: It does not work with the tex file from last year anymore, that is somehow the mystery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your settings don't set `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight`. And so graphicx will reset `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` at the begin of the document to letter.

Add this to your template:

```
\setlength{\paperwidth}{180mm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{237mm}
```

Comment: I still don't understand why it worked last year, but now I am very happy, that the solution is so easy, thank you :)

Comment: Your code was faulty as it didn't set paperwidth. In older tex systems this error was ignored but newer versions of graphicx set the pdfpagewidth equal to paperwidth.